# Python Accessing to the parent class (Not inheritance)

Tags: python, class, oop

Is possible access to the parent methods/properties in a class that are inside of the other class?

```
class ClassA:
    a = 'a'

    class ClassB():
        def method(self):
            return self.a

instance = ClassA()
instance2 = instance.ClassB()
instance2.method()
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, nesting a class doesn't automatically produce a relationship between instances. All you did was create an attribute on `ClassA` that happens to be a class object. Calling that attribute on instances just finds the class attribute and a new instance of `ClassB` is created without any knowledge of or reference to the `ClassA` instance.

You'll need to make such relationships explicit by passing in a reference:

```
class ClassB():
    def __init__(self, a):
        self.a = a

    def method(self):
        return self.a

class ClassA:
    a = 'a'

    def class_b_factory(self):
        return ClassB(self)


instance = ClassA()
instance2 = instance.class_b_factory()
instance2.method()
```

Comment: @thefourtheye: It's the correct name to use though; classes are instance factories, meta classes are class factories, etc. When using a function solely to produce an object in a specific context, using `factory` in the name is fine, unless the specific context gives you a better name. There is no context here to speak of though..